# How can I add a comma to a number input field to get more than one recode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an if statement with two parameter conditions to meet. It should then execute but in the text field I can only put one form number the other one can't.

This is my js

my function is working but the text field here is my problem

---

```
  function analyedata() {
$('#norecordalert').addClass('hidden');
$('#connection-error').addClass('hidden');
$('#apperror-id').addClass('hidden');

var nin = $("#data").val();
if (nin == "0015") {

    $('#apperror-id').addClass('hidden');
    $('#detailsDiv').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#data1').removeClass('hidden');
}
else if ((nin =="0017")&&(nin =="0019")) {


    $('#apperror-id').addClass('hidden');
    $('#detailsDiv').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#data1').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#data2').removeClass('hidden');
}
else if ((nin =="0012")&&(nin=="0013")&&(nin=="0011")) {

    $('#apperror-id').addClass('hidden');
    $('#detailsDiv').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#data1').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#data2').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#data3').removeClass('hidden');

}
else {
    $('#loadingid').addClass('hidden');
    $('#containerDiv').css('display', 'none');
    swal("Oops!", "Recorde Not Found!!", "error")
        .then(() => {
            $('#containerDiv').css('display', 'block');
        });

};
```

I expect it to display more than one recodes

Comment: How can a string equal 2 or more things? If the string has multiple parts, you need to either split it up or use indexOf/contains.

Comment: Needs some more work than just this, but the basic is:  `var ninlist = $("#data").val().split(','); for (var i=0;i<ninlist.length; ++i) { var nin = ninlist[0]; if (nin == "0015") ...`

Comment: i have a input field that by the function it should display  a certain div if I tried displaying one dive at a time it works and also if I tried to display the div by ether of the parameters it also work but if I want it to display the div when the parameters both are certified then it will not because in the text field I can only enter a single id

Comment: @freedomn-m please what i mean is how can i make it from the input field to enter 2 values which the js can read

Comment: Ah the crux is in the title (not in the question): *how can I add [a] comma to a number input* - remove the number input restriction and make it a normal text input, then parse the numbers have give errors.   You could also check for non-number/-comma on `input` event, but this generally results in a bad UX.  The other option is to tokenise the input, in the same way the SO tags input works, but with numbers.

Comment: Please provide an example of the content that might be added to text field.

Comment: @Twisty if am having two recodes to compare then I will want to enter their form number and separate them by a comma to get them both e.g  0012,0015 in the input text

Comment: @kamalAliyu I posted an answer based on what I think you mean, but it's really unclear as you have not provided an actual example. Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on some of the comments, I suspect you're working with something like:

```
001100120013001500170019
```

If this is the case, and the string will ALWAYS be 4 digits that you are looking for, you have a number of options. Basically, you're going to chunk this string into parts. You can pop the first 4 and repeat or look for specific patterns with a Regular Expression.

```js
$(function() {
  function chunkFour(s, p, d) {
    var results = [];
    var i = 0;
    while (i < s.length) {
      results.push(s.slice(i, i + p));
      i += p;
    }
    return results.join(d);
  }

  function regFour(s, p, d) {
    var regex = new RegExp("(\\d{" + p + "})", "g");
    var match = [];
    while ((m = regex.exec(s)) !== null) {
      // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
      if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
      }
      match.push(m[0]);
    }
    return match.join(d);
  }

  $("button").click(function() {
    var task = $(this).attr("id");
    var inp = $("#recode").val().trim();
    var r;
    $("#result").val("");
    if (task == "chunk") {
      r = chunkFour(inp, 4, ",");
    } else {
      r = regFour(inp, 4, ",");
    }
    $("#result").val(r);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <p>Recode <input id="recode" type="text" value="001100120013001500170019" />
</div>
<button id="chunk">Chunk</button> <button id="regex">RegEx</button>
<div>
  <p>Result <input id="result" type="text" />
</div>
```

So as you can see, here are two ways to break up a string of numbers so that you can work with them. Putting them into arrays allows for a lot of functionality, like sorting or comparing. What you do with it is up to you.

**Update** I adjusted the functions to be more flexible. So you can look for 2 numbers or can separate them with `|` if you like.

Comment: The issue is that OP can't seem to get over that input type=number doesn't allow anything other numeric and they simply need to stop using input type=number to allow commas/pipes `|`/etc

Comment: @freedomn-m I suspect you are right yet I am not sure how you concluded that since OP never posted any HTML, so we do not know what input type they are using. They say `"0011"` which you can't get with type="number" if I recall.

Comment: I may, of course, be incorrect.  The question title states *"add a comma to a number input field"* - if it wasn't `type=number`, then you'd be able to enter a comma.   Then there's a comment *"because in the text field I can only enter a single id"*.  You can enter leading zeros into a type=number field (just checked in Chrome at least)

Comment: @freedomn-m I see what you're saying. Hard to know either way.